# Flutter TCP Socket with Python send any different string

Tags: python, flutter, tcpsocket, ssid, p-lang

I'm trying send data to python on flutter. But I am only send "data", ı want send different "string" but this code not working. I want to send "psk" and "ssid" string. Can you help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tcp_socket_connection/tcp_socket_connection.dart';

class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UsersPageState createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TcpSocketConnection socketConnection =
      TcpSocketConnection("my_ip", 9000); 
  String message = "";
  String ssid = "";
  String psk = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startConnection();
  }

  //receiving and sending back a custom message
  void messageReceived(String msg) {
    setState(() {
      message = msg;
    });
  }

  //starting the connection and listening to the socket asynchronously
  void startConnection() async {
    socketConnection.enableConsolePrint(
        true); //use this to see in the console what's happening
    if (await socketConnection.canConnect(20000000, attempts: 1)) {
      //check if it's possible to connect to the endpoint
      await socketConnection.connect(2000000, messageReceived, attempts: 1);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Wifi Name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.wifi),
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {
                    ssid = text;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Wifi Password',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {
                    psk = text;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  socketConnection.isConnected();
                  socketConnection.sendMessage(ssid);
                  socketConnection.disconnect();
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
                  socketConnection.connect(5000, messageReceived);
                },
                child: Text('SSİD'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  socketConnection.isConnected();
                  socketConnection.sendMessage(psk);
                  socketConnection.disconnect();
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
                  socketConnection.connect(5000, messageReceived);
                },
                child: Text('PSK'),
              ),
            ])));
  }
}
```

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 9000))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024) 
    psk = str(clientsocket.recv(1024))
    ssid = str(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
    print(ssid)
    print(psk)
    print(data)
```

I try send data on flutter tcp socket-->Python but I only send "data". I want to send different string (example: "ssid" and "psk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following parts to the flutter code to send a different string. And it worked I was able to send a new string. Here is the new code. I just changed these.

```
  void messageReceivedd(String psk) {
setState(() {
  wifi = psk;
});}
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              socketConnection.isConnected();
              socketConnection.sendMessage(wifi);
              socketConnection.disconnect();
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
              socketConnection.connect(5000, messageReceivedd);
```